# Auto-adopt <img> height to <h2> height

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to auto-adopt the < img> height to < h2> height.

*Technically speaking:* for example, if the "height" value for < img> is 70px, the "height" value for < h2> should be 70px as well.

*Figuratively speaking:* The image height should "end" at the underlining of the last row of < h2>.

So when headline has less characters, the image should automatically get smaller. Do I need javascript for this or can I do this purely with CSS?

Look at the example below, so you understand what I mean:

> The given attributes for < img> (float:right) and < div> (max-width:
>   70%) should not be changed, but additional attributes can be added.

```css
img {
  float: right;
}

div {
  max-width: 70%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/pineapple.jpg" alt=""></a>
  <h2><a href="#">Dolor Ipsum sol kinetus valis dolor alem est gillado fam</a></h2>
</div>
```

Comment: haven't you tried anything in javascript for that? 
probably you will need JS. add an `id` to the `img` and to `h2` then get the h2 height and set it to the img

Comment: I'm a beginner in Javascript, could you explain the steps a little more detailed?

Comment: read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle
and this: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_style.asp

Comment: How wide do should your h2 and img be with respect to each other? 30/70?

Comment: h2 width 60, img width 40

Comment: got it work :-)

Comment: Image should follow title or title should follow image?